# function should return the contents of the parentheses. If no text appears in parentheses, return an empty string

Tags: python, string

Here's my code

```
def in_parentheses(string):
    txt = string[string.find("(")+1:string.find(")")]
    return txt
```

Comment: `find()` returns `-1` if it can't find the character. You need to check for that. Or you could just use a regular expression.

Comment: You should also start searching for `)` at the position of `(`. The second argument to `find()` is useful for this.